# SQL date filter operator

Tags: sql, operators, filtering, presto

Just a general date filter question, what are the valid operators for me to filter a specific timeframe as I had this error:

> Cannot apply operator: date <= varchar(8)

code:

```sql
where utc_date >= '2022-04-01'
```

data type = date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'2022-04-01'` is a varchar literal, you need to convert it to date for example by prefixing it with [`date`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html?highlight=literal#date):

```sql
where utc_date >= date '2022-04-01'
```